# Ingenuity in mathematics

Tags: big-list

[This is just the kind of vague community-wiki question that I would almost certainly turn my nose up at if it were asked by someone else, so I apologise in advance, but these sorts of questions do come up on MO with some regularity now so I thought I'd try my luck]

I have just been asked by the Royal Society of Arts to come along to a lunchtime seminar on "ingenuity". As you can probably guess from the location, this is not a mathematical event. In the email to me with the invitation, it says they're inviting me "...as I suppose that some
mathematical proofs exhibit ingenuity in their methods." :-)

The email actually *defines* ingenuity for me: it says it's "ideas that solve a
problem in an unusually neat, clever, or surprising way.". My instinct now would *usually* be to collect a bunch of cute low-level mathematical results with snappy neat clever and/or surprising proofs, e.g. by scouring my memory for such things, over the next few weeks, and then to casually drop some of them into the conversation.

My instinct now, however, is to ask here first, and go back to the old method if this one fails.

### Question: What are some mathematical results with surprising and/or unusually neat proofs?

Now let's see whether this question (a) bombs, (b) gets closed, (c) gets filled with rubbish,  (d) gets filled with mostly rubbish but a couple of gems, which I can use to amuse, amaze and impress my lunchtime arty companions and get all the credit myself.

This is Community Wiki of course, and I won't be offended if the general consensus is that these adjectives apply to the vast majority of results and the question gets closed. I'm not so sure they do though---sometimes the proof is "grind it out". Although I don't think I'll be telling the Royal Society of Arts people this, I always felt that Mazur's descent to prove his finiteness results for modular curves was pretty surprising (in that he had enough data to pull the descent off). But I'm sure there are some really neat low-level answers to this.

Comment: I'm in a mellow mood and shan't vote to close, but I think that as penance for asking the question you should do a report on the seminar for us.  Slightly more seriously, I think it'll be quite an amazing result that a) has a surprising proof, b) is explainable to non-mathematicians, and c) the fact that the proof is surprising is explainable to non-mathematicians.

Comment: Given the low levelness requirement you might want to peruse the math puzzles for dinner thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29323/math-puzzles-for-dinner

Some of these problems have pretty snappy proofs.

Comment: +1 for 'I suppose that some mathematical proofs exhibit ingenuity'. Two cultures, anyone?

Comment: Check out http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words

Comment: @Andrew: here's a contender, which I thought of on the walk through Hyde Park to the tube: "what is 1+2+3+4+...+1000?" plus obvious ingenious trick to solve it (possibly illustrated by my waving a piece of paper around with two triangles put together to make a rectangle). Actually this reminds me that I sholuld check out the proofs without words thread.

Comment: Kevin: doesn't do it for me.  Why would I be interested in the sum of the first 1000 numbers?  Sounds like the sort of thing my kids would do before they knew any better.

Comment: Thinking a little more about this, I suspect that you're going to get two types of answer.  There's the "trick question", where there's some simple problem that if you see the trick, it's trivial (sum of numbers, or fly-between-cars falls in to this category).  If you want them, I've got some books that might interest you (and some shares in Northern Rock, can I sell you them while I'm at it? - sorry, don't know where that came from).  Or there's the deep theorems that people banged their heads against for years before someone came along and said, "Oh, but it's obvious because ...". (ctd)


Comment: (ctd) and such that even _now_ when someone reads the ingenious proof it is _still_ ingenious.  That's the problem with trick ones: once you've seen it, it's no longer fun - it's like a joke that you've heard before.  You remember that it's funny, and remember why, but somehow it just isn't as good the second time around.  But by asking here, you've set yourself up as a Representative of Mathematicians!  So to avoid us being stereotyped (again) as Nerds who study Spherical Horses in Vacuums, I really hope that you get some good ones of the second variety.  (ctd again)

Comment: (ctd again) You probably won't be able to drop them in casually in conversation, but if you can get someone to actually listen to you (yeah, yeah, I know), and explain exactly what was so amazing about X's ingenious proof of Y, then you might have actually Done Some Good.  Anyway, good luck to you and I'll be keeping an eye on the answers!

Comment: I think, by the way, that "I need some examples for a talk" is a completely legitimate excuse for a big-list community wiki question.

Comment: Of course "I need some examples for a talk" is only a stone's throw away from "I need someone to do my homework for me" :-). And I feel about as lazy as the homework cheat: 2 years ago I would have just, once every few days, spent 5 minutes trying to remember some more examples stuck in my head somewhere, and then just talked about them.

Comment: I don't feel like answering per se. But how about the napkin ring problem? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37295/advanced-view-of-the-napkin-ring-problem

Comment: @Kevin: re: sum of first 1000 numbers, you could probably do worse than to mention something along the following lines: http://books.google.com/books?id=-7HaqS7YVDsC&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=%22infant+gauss%22&source=bl&ots=OrAgx_e1zM&sig=dV2uIOlZVZMdpwABxFuLE5zkgS0&hl=en&ei=E1yjTIaGC8T_lgfi-q3FBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22infant%20gauss%22&f=false

Comment: @Andrew: here's a brief report on the seminar. People talked about ingenuity by example (I got the dominoes example in, in a small discussion) and various "definitions" of ingenuity (most of which I found a bit unsatisfactory, especially when people tried to quantify how ingenious something was by some sort of information-theory methods or something). In some sense the best bit about the seminar was various silly stories about people getting their windscreen wipers working again using pieces of string and pullies etc etc. Computer proofs were touched on, which was nice.

Answer (score 76):

"At any party, there are at least two people with the same number of friends there".

This typically won't be obvious to someone who isn't a mathematician. However, it's quite easy for many people to see this by picturing everyone at the party wearing a t-shirt displaying how many of their friends are present. The number of possible t-shirts is one less than the number of attendees, so there must be a double somewhere.

Comment: You need a little more to complete the proof, since, for $n$ people at the party, there are, a priori, $n$ possible t-shirts, bearing the numbers 0 through $n-1$.  The extra step you need is that 0 and $n-1$ can't both occur (though either one can).  

Comment: That's a good point. If I were explaining that to an artist, I'd say that we require the people with no friends at the party to step outside for a second...

Comment: Another way to account for the $n-1$ possible t-shirts is the way the part is organised: the host invites friends and then they invite some more friends. So everyone there has at least one friend who invited them along (with the exception of the host, but unless he's a bit wierd he presumably invites at least one friend to his party!!)

Comment: [Pedantic note: 0 and n - 1 can both occur if there is only 1 person at the party. But perhaps it is implicit in "party" that there are at least two people.]

Answer (score 62):

There are irrational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^y$ is rational. For consider $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$. This number is either rational or irrational. If it's rational then we're done. Otherwise, it's irrational, and $(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}})^{\sqrt{2}} = 2$, so we're still done.

Comment: I thought this was very cool when I saw it first. But doesn't the same claim hold with more prosaic choices for $x,y$ like $e^{\ln 2}$?

Comment: This is my favorite example of a non-constructive proof.

Comment: @Dinesh: but then you first have to prove that $e$ and $ln 2$ are irrational, which is slightly harder than the proof of irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Well, let's choose $x=\sqrt{2}$, $y=2\log_2 3$. It is easy to prove that both $x$, $y$ are irrational.

Comment: While I like this result, I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing that will really "wow" a room full of artists, for whom (I imagine) notions of rationality and irrationality aren't familiar enough for this to be anything more than a remote curiosity.

Comment: i taught a class for gifted 8-10 year olds this summer and one of them showed me this proof!

Comment: @DerrickStolee Same for me. I use it to show that "constructive" can be a nuanced concept. This proof is non-constructive in the weakest possible sense, in fact. It provides you with two computable objects, and you know one of them has the desired property. You just don't know which.

Comment: It is a very beautiful argument. Except that we of course know which of the two is irrational (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) ;-)

Answer (score 51):

One of my favorites is *von Neumann's randomness extractor*:

Suppose you have a biased coin that comes up heads with probability $p$ and tails with $q=1-p$. How do you construct an unbiased coin from the biased one?

The answer is simple but really nice. Simply toss the bad coin twice, and discard $HH$ and $TT$. The other two events occur with equal probabilities, $pq$ and $qp$.

[Wikipedia link: Randomness extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor)

Answer (score 49):

The impossibility of tiling a chessboard with two opposite corners removed using dominos is quite good for this purpose I think, especially if you start by giving a boring case-analysis proof for a 4-by-4 board.

The bridges of Königsberg is also pretty good. Marcus du Sautoy spoke about it last night in his series A Brief History of Mathematics on Radio 4 (though he overdid it when he claimed that the solution had "revolutionized the internet").

Comment: +1 for the chess board. It's my canonical example for such occasions.

Comment: Nice!
here is a link: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00srz5b

Comment: The chessboard problem can be nicely continued by proving that the chessboard can be tiled with dominos if two differently coloured squares are removed. Check out the solution of puzzle B at  http://gurmeetsingh.wordpress.com/2008/09/12/puzzle-tiling-a-chessboard-with-dominoes/

Comment: There is also the one with L-shaped tiles.

Answer (score 29):

On the walk home I remembered the following. You play a game with a friend. The friend deals from a pack of cards, turning each card face up one by one. After each card, you have the opportinity to say "STOP" (and after the 51st card has been turned over you *have* to say "STOP"). The next card is then turned over, and you win if it's red. Can you devise a strategy which enables you to win on average with probability over 50 percent?

Comment: To complete the triviality of the situation, after your audience proposes a bunch of complex strategies, propose an alternative game whereby after "STOP" it's the *last* card in the deck that gets turned over. Everyone sees that *this* game is strategy-indifferent, and then you deliver the coup de grace... I've used this several times in math circles. Gets them every time.

Answer (score 29):

Here is a proof of Pythagoras's theorem that I like:

- You want to prove that the sum of the squares on each of the non-hypotenuse sides equals
  the square on the hypotenuse.
- You generalize, and instead prove that for *any* shape, if you scale it by $a$, and then by $b$, the sum of the resulting areas is the area of the shape scaled by $c$.  (We began with the case of the unit square.)
- By thinking about how areas scale,
  it suffices to check for one particular shape.
- We check it by taking the shape to be the original triangle (to be pedantic: scaled so that its hypotenuse has length one).  This case is clear: just drop a perpendicular from the vertex opposite the
  hypotenuse to the hypotenuse, and see note that the triangle with hypotenuse length $c$
  is the sum of two similar triangle of hypotenuse lengths $a$ and $b$.

Obviously you are not going to drop this into casual conversation: it requires a focused effort at explanation.  But I think it illustrates something true, and fairly general, about how mathematicians argue.

For example, the squares that we are adding get transmuted from areas of specific shapes, to scaling factors for areas of quite general shapes.  This lets us go from checking something tricky (or trying to make tricky geometric constructions with the squares on the three sides, to see how they are related) to checking something that is immediately obvious.  So we also see two kinds of ingenuity: the ingenious reinterpretation
of the meaning of the squares (ingenious on a conceptual level, which is certainly a very common form of mathematical ingenuity), and the ingenuity of drawing a single line on the original triangle to break it into two triangles similar to itself (which is ingenious on a more visceral level --- a single stroke of ingenuity).

One other advantage: the other participants quite likely have heard of Pythagoras's theorem, and may even remember it, but are unlikely to know a proof.  (Or do painters have some training in Euclidean geometry?)  Knowing the result, they may be better positioned to appreciate the ingenuity of the proof.

Also: this argument appeared somewhere else recently on MO, I think, but I forget where.
(Added: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40005/generalizing-a-problem-to-make-it-easier/40020#40020), in a reponse of Dick Palais to Timothy Gowers's question about making something easier by generalization.)

Comment: I heard this first in a lecture by Hyman Bass many years ago.  By the way, aren't painters supposed to know perspective, which beget projective geometry ?

Comment: I love this argument. Even if not everyone in your talks follows it, it'll be worth it for the people who do follow it.

Comment: Dear Chandan,  Regarding your comment about perspective, it is precisely the fact that, of all non-scientists, painters might be one group of people who nevertheless know geometry, which caused me to ask my parenthetical question.

Comment: I first came across this argument in Induction and Analogy in Mathematics, by Polya. As he says, the proof is due to Euclid, but this beautiful way of generating it may possibly be due to Polya himself. (He says that the relevant section of the book reproduces with minor changes a note of his in the American Mathematical Monthly of 1948.) I once discussed it in a public lecture and I think it served its purpose well.

Comment: This is a beautiful argument, similar to a problem in Harold Jacobs' lovely high school geometry book, but the original theorem of Pythagoras, as it first occurs in Euclid is different. The difference is in the meaning of the word "equal", which in Euclid does not mean same numerical area. Neither the concepts of area nor of proportion were available at that point in the book, so his less sophisticated proof is essentially to display compatible finite decompositions of the three figures involved. The wonderful proof here thus uses rather more sophisticated ideas which we now take for granted.

Comment: Dear Roy,

Thanks for your thoughtful remarks.  I agree that the ideas in this
argument are quite sophisticated (so it is perhaps as much an example of *depth of ideas* in mathematics at of *ingenuity*).  Best wishes, Matthew

Comment: Matthew, I am teaching Euclid to brilliant 8-10 year olds, and seeing how useful similarity is.  If one accepts it as a postulate many theorems are easy: Pythagoras, "power of the point", construction of a regular pentagon.  Perhaps the message I am getting at last from your example, is that similarity is so important as a unifying principle that it should be introduced as early as possible. In logical sequence, one might prove classical Pythagoras, develop similarity with it (via Prop.III.35 of Euclid), then give this example of how similarity generalizes Pythagoras. thank you for this, roy

Comment: update: Matthew, finally appreciating similarity has made me change my whole focus for the 2 week course.  after aiming at a big finale presenting Euclid's tour de force proof of proposition IV.10 for constructing a pentagon, i finally realized that similarity makes the proof so much easier i can actually remember it, and can finesse two preliminary somewhat unfamiliar lemmas, as well as present an important tool, SAS similarity, to the kids.  so today i will do it that way.  (we do have similarity  legitimately now by virtue of prop. III.35, but i had not realized its value.) thanks again!

Comment: Dear Roy, Thanks very much for your comments.  I'm glad that this example has been stimulating for your class, and would enjoy hearing how it goes.  (Well, I hope!)  Best wishes, Matthew

Comment: It went well and I was glad I used the more powerful similarity approach for two reasons.  1) they learned a more generally useful idea.  2) I finished in the alloted time!

Comment: as gowers says, exactly this proof is due to Euclid, in prop. VI.31.  I.e. after presenting the theory of similarity Euclid gives this generalization of Pythagoras as an application of similarity.

Answer (score 27):

There is the old classic of a fly flying between two trains.

Comment: I thought it was Gordon Baker's dog ...

Comment: I failed that one on a problem solving course exam.it's really more common sense then mathematics or physics.

Comment: There is a great story about von Neumann being presented with this problem, which he answered instantaneously. "Aha! So you knew how to do it in a clever way. Most people are trying to sum the series, you know". - "What do you mean? That's what I did!".

Comment: Because it is his series?

Answer (score 27):

Linear algebra proof of Binet's formula for Fibonacci numbers.

Fibonacci numbers satisfy

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{n} = \begin{pmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_{n} \\\\ F_{n} & F_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$

Diagonalize the matrix on left.

Comment: That's a really cool one,Fubini. John Kennedy showed to me originally and it shows the power of linear algebra manifesting in a really unexpected place.

Comment: In fact, I'd go with the identity $F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_n^2=(-1)^n$ instead of the Binet formula.

Comment: This is indeed a cool fact.  However, I am certain any non-math person would be lost at the term matrix, let alone diagonalize, especially when said non-math people merely suppose some mathematical proofs exhibit ingenuity :)

Comment: @AndrewL: It's never surprising when the power of linear algebra manifests itself.

Answer (score 22):

You run a knockout tournament. Some good players get seeded to later rounds, and some players get byes if there are an odd number of players left. How many matches are necessary? (OK, it's well known and completely trivial, but you did imply that you would be talking to artists....)

Comment: @Richard: that's a super example of what I had in mind. 

Answer (score 22):

Alex R's answer reminds me of another sort of clever "strategy" problem. The way I've heard it phrased is as follows (with apologies to the vegetarians in the audience):

You are given 1000 cups filled with water, exactly one of which (unknown to you) is laced with a lethal poison that is guaranteed to kill within 24 hours if ingested. You are given ten rats with which to determine the poisoned cup. What is the minimum amount of time needed to be certain?

One naive approach would be to break up the cups into groups of 100 to be fed to each rat (i.e. rat 1 gets cups 1 through 100, rat 2 gets 101 through 200 etc). After 24 hours one rat will be dead and you have narrowed the poisoned cup to one in 100. Repeat two more times: you have your poisoned cup identified within 72 hours.

There is in fact a much better solution, which identifies the cup in the minimal 24 hours. Since $1000~<~2^{10} = 1024$, assign each cup a number expressed in binary. Then give the water in that cup to those rats for which there is a '1' in the binary representation (so, for example, cup 17 = 10001 is fed to rats 1 and 5). After 24 hours, you can simply read off the number of the poisoned cup by the numbers of the dead rats.

You can impress your audience with the remarkable (some might say brutal) efficiency of this procedure: to identify one in a million cups you would need only 20 rats (ignoring, of course, any deaths caused by overhydration...)

Comment: This answer is great; I think it can be made a little more transparent but should be perfect for the kind of talk Kevin describes.  

Comment: Anyone who likes this problem might also enjoy thinking about the generalization where two or more cups are poisoned, which seems much harder to me: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639/logic-problem-identifying-poisoned-wines-out-of-a-sample-minimizing-test-subjec

Comment: I have known this exact problem to come up in interviews for industry jobs (e.g. jobs with Google or IBM, though I can't remember which company asked this question)

Answer (score 20):

Does the problem of [The Monkey and the Coconuts](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math106s206/ex/coconut.pdf) count?

Comment: I think Franz was suggesting the negative solution as his submission.  Isn't that the whole point of this exercise?  Find ways that replace brute-forcing your way to a solution with a non-obvious insight (that $-4$ is a solution, and solutions are periodic mod $5^4$) that depends on some knowledge of slightly non-trivial mathematics?

Answer (score 14):

I like evaluating the integral
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx.
$$

Answer (score 13):

Certainly Cantor diagonalization? You have Russell's paradox, which is perfectly understandable to the lay person, going to the uncountability of reals, going to Godel's incompleteness. I think each incarnation passes Andrew Stacey's tests...

Comment: *NERD ALERT NERD ALERT* I have tried explaining Cantor's Diagonal Argument to my girlfriend. Eew. On a very long bus journey in Bolivia. Well, we had got bored of looking out of the window...Anyway, my point is that she's got quite a scientific brain (she's a doctor) but it took a fair while to explain it to her, despite the fact that she was (or at least seemed) genuinely keen to understand my comment that "there is more than one kind of infinity". I'm not convinced I'm going to convince a painter of this over lunch :-)

Comment: I agree with Kevin on this one.  I have a suspicion that: #(people who understand the setup) - #(people for whom the proof isn't "what else could it be?") = #(cranks who keep posting on the arXiv).

Comment: What I had in mind when I wrote "Russell's paradox" is the barber paradox version. I think it can be understood by a painter. If it helps, you can even turn it into a painter paradox version, with the painter drawing portraits! The second part, about Cantor or Godel, can be put into language very similar to the barber paradox. While I don't expect a painter to understand all the words that fit in these statements, it should be possible to explain the similarity with the more tangible barber paradox. And you can confidently say that this idea has revolutionized math twice in the past century.



Comment: I plead guilty to being a nerd, in any case.

Comment: I'm a nerd,too. And thier incomprehensibility won't stop me from trying to explain it to the painter,Kevin.I figure if I can explain that to a painter,explaining the Sylow theorums to a room full of math undergraduates should be a cakewalk.

Comment: I barely ever log into this stack exchange; I just browse. But the low score on this answer bugged me. It's a fantastic answer. I roomed with an art major my second and third year of college. He is particularly bright and very multi-talented individual but not trained in mathematics to any capacity. He understood Cantor's Diagonalization easily and declared, "Ross, you just blew my mind!" (as though the proof were my own.) Douglas Hofstadter provides a really simple explanation of all three of these suggestions. I might suggest skipping (the proof of) Godel's Incompleteness Thm., though.

Answer (score 13):

> **Theorem [Inaba].** Any configuration of 10 points in
>   the plane can be covered by disjoint unit disks.

**Proof.** Put a dense packing of unit disks on the plane at random.

[image]

Then the average number of covered points is $10\cdot \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}=9.069\ldots>9.$

See [Covering Points with Disjoint Unit Disks](http://2012.cccg.ca/papers/paper13.pdf) for the history.

Answer (score 11):

How about the classic 20 prisoner problem. A warden tells 20 prisoners that they can live if they survive the following game: tomorrow the warden will line up the prisoners single file (at random), facing forward and place either a red or blue hat on each prisoner. Each prisoner can only see the color of hats infront of him. The warden starts from the back of the line and asks each prisoner in turn what color hat they think they are wearing. If a prisoner answers correctly they live, otherwise they die. No communication is allowed between prisoners once the game starts and they can only shout "red" or "blue" when it's their turn. The prisoners have the evening to discuss a strategy.What is the best strategy for the prisoners? How many prisoners can be guaranteed to live.

Comment: This is a really good one in terms of (a) a surprising result, (b) a clever idea, and (c) it's explainable to non-mathematicians (especially because the general public nowadays "gets" binary arithmetic a little better than they would have, say, fifty years ago).  Plus you could tie this in to error-correcting codes and actually have a real-world application!

Comment: There is an infinite version (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoners_and_hats_puzzle) too. Not for the general audience but very interesting if you're into axiom of choice and infinities.

Comment: Apart from being not for the general audience, I think that it's also wrong. It relies on a kind of constructive version of the axiom of choice, which of course doesn't exist, otherwise it wouldn't have to be an axiom. The AC is an existence statement and not a procedure for making a choice. In particular the sentence from the wikipedia page "Using the axiom of choice, they select and memorize a representative sequence from each equivalence class" doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: "Using the axiom of choice, they select and memorize a representative sequence from each equivalence class" doesn't make any sense to me.. Alex, will you be happier with "Using the axiom of choice, we can show that there exists a strategy (a mapping that takes in the position number and the tail seen from this position and outputs the hat color) that makes only finitely many errors for every input sequence"? I mean, "prisoners", "hats", and "memorize" are just colorful words here and the implied translation into the formal language is rather obvious, so what do you object? 

Answer (score 11):

The game of chomp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp where player 1 has a winning strategy, but no one really knows how to find it.

It's a neat example of a nonconstructive proof of existence (and has a short proof).

Comment: I know how to find it.  Wanna play chomp?

Answer (score 10):

Sylvester-Gallai Theorem:

n points in the 2D plane, not all collinear. There is a line which passes through exactly two points.

Proof: Dualize. Points<->Lines. In dual, we need to show no more than 3 lines intersect. Consider intersection points and lines as planar graph. Planar graphs have nodes with degree no more than 5. Done.

Comment: I think, it is not so easy, because the infinite rays are not edges of our graph... The usuaL trick is to consider all the staff on a sphere.

Answer (score 10):

First, I'd suggest Eratosthenes's method of computing the radius of the Earth, unless it is really well-known to them.

Otherwise, here's a nice one. You go for a bike ride. At the end, each wheel has made a closed simple curve, and, suppose, you noticed that these two curves never met. What's the area encosed between them? The distance between the centers of the wheels is $r$.

*Answer* : $\pi r^2.$ *Explanation*: the line passing for the two contact points of the wheels on the ground, is tangent to the back wheel's curve, and during the trip, it made a complete $2\pi$ rotation. *To convince your audience:* imagine a disk (a pizza) cut into several very thin slices (with vertex in the center as usual). Make the slices slide on each other, so that a hole appears in the middle of the pizza. The curve bounding the hole is the one traced by the back wheel; the exterior boundary is the curve traced by the other wheel.

```
                                   <           
                                  /___~ 
                                () \- ()
```

Comment: I'd like to see a picture of that bike!

Comment: done. A pizza bike for you! 

Answer (score 10):

Consider a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ starting at 0. At each step either add 1 or subtract 1, with probability 1/2 each. Let $0\neq i\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. What is the probability $P_n(i)$ that $i$ is the last point to remain unvisited?

**Solution.** Consider the first time the walk reaches a point adjacent to $i$ (either $i-1$ or $i+1$). The probability that $i$ is the last point to remain unvisited is then the probability that the walk visits the other point adjacent to $i$ before visiting $i$. This probability is independent of $i$. Hence $P_n(i)=1/(n-1)$. (I don't know the origin of this classic problem.)

Answer (score 9):

Solving a math problem by appeal to electricity is pretty creative in my opinion.  Check out [squaring the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square).

Comment: Much of Stas Smirnov's recent work is based on trying to extend the "discrete complex analysis" behind that example to other difficult problems.

Answer (score 9):

The [Monty Hall Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) is one possibility.  I usually pose the problem as, "Should you always switch or always stay or does it even matter?"  The argument that switching is the best strategy is itself not especially neat from a mathematical point-of-view, but since the result completely defies human intuition, I think the proof seems quite ingenious, especially to people outside math.  It certainly solves a problem in a surprising or unusual way in that the answer is shocking.  If you decide to do it, I would recommend bringing in 3 cards (two spades and a heart, say) as props to aid in your explanation and discussion.

Comment: No, there is an easy way to convince an audience of the true answer. You ask: at the end of the game, when facing the final choice, what is the probability that the other door is the good one? If at the start I chose the good door, then now the other door is empty. If at the start I chose a bad door, which is 2 times out of 3, then now the other door is the good one. So, 2 times out of 3, it's better to switch.

Comment: I completely agree that it is not hard to convince people of the answer (especially when you explain visually what's happening with some props), but I have never met anyone who instinctively would answer that it's better to switch.  The result is extremely counterintuitive to essentially everyone, well-educated or not.  It's the kind of problem where most people will struggle and disagree with you at first until they have a eureka moment and it suddenly seems so obvious.

Comment: Much easier explanation: Suppose there are a hundred doors...

Comment: The problem with explaining this to a general audience is not that they won't believe your explanation of why it's 1/3 to 2/3, but rather that they will generate one or more explanations of why it's even probability, believe those too, and get confused.

Comment: That's interesting to hear, Elizabeth.  I've almost always had the opposite experience, where they don't believe me and spend a great deal of energy arguing their point.

Comment: @Elizabeth and Peter: If you change the problem from three doors to a hundred doors, with Monty Hall opening up 98 of them, the correct answer immediately becomes clear.  Then ask the audience what happens when Monty Hall opens 98-n of 100-n doors as n increases.  This is another case of generalizing the problem to make the answer more obvious.  

Answer (score 9):

One of my students created the following proof that the medians of a triangle are concurrent while waiting to talk to me in office hours.

Choose any two medians.

1)  the two medians do meet somewhere inside the triangle.

2)  If we join the centers of the three sides, obtaining a "central triangle",

then the two given medians are also medians of that central triangle,

hence their meeting point is also inside that triangle.

3)  We are done.

I.e. iterating the procedure shows that any two  medians meet at the unique point common to all central triangles.

Comment: You need to show that the triangles doesn't have more than one common point: You could make this "proof" for any three lines from the vertices to the opposite sides. The difference is, that for the median, the area of the central triangles goes to 0, but it doesn't in general.

Comment: this is a good point.  I was hoping this proof would work also in "neutral" geometry, but exactly the point you mention seems to fail there.  I.e. this theorem is true in both Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry, but I have not seen a proof that works in both cases.

Answer (score 8):

How about the fact that in hex the first player has a winning [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument)?

Answer (score 8):

The RSA algorithm publicly described in 1978 by Ron Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Leonard Adleman at MIT is a classic example of "Ingenuinity in Mathematics". Its the famous Public Key Cryptography scheme widely used everywhere and is solidly founded on Mathematics.

Answer (score 7):

I think the 3 children with dirty faces puzzle is a good one for this type of talk (also referred to as the "blue-eyed islanders puzzle" on Tao's blog http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/the-blue-eyed-islanders-puzzle/):

I came home yesterday to find that my 3 kids had been playing rugby and all had dirty foreheads.  I told them that whoever could tell me whether their own forehead was dirty would get a shiny new bike.  After looking at each other for a moment, they seemed uncertain.  I asked again, "No ones knows?"  Still no reply.  Finally I shrugged and said, "Well, if you can't tell me then no one gets a bike," at which point all three simultaneously shouted: "My forehead is dirty!".

Answer (score 6):

Mathematicians are used to seeing these sorts of problems and are generally more intrigued by their solutions, but I came across this recently:

Colour every point in the plane either black or white.

Fix any positive distance $d$.

Can I find two identically coloured points which are a distance $d$ apart?

Answer: Of course. Look at the vertices of an equilateral triangle of side length $d$.

Comment: Actually the argument for three colors is even more beautiful. This was a Putnam problem from many decades ago.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem

Answer (score 5):

The problem:

A rectangle R can be tiled with smaller rectangles such that

- The sides of the smaller rectanges are parallel the sides of R.
- At least one side of each of the smaller rectangle is integral.

Show that at least one side of R is integral.

The proof:

Consider $\iint_{R} e^{2 \pi i (x+y)} dxdy$

This is zero, by adding up along each small rectangle. The result follows.

Comment: I think an analogous proof that can be explained to artists is to tile the rectangle w/ a black and white checkerboard parallel to the rectangles with squares of width 1/2. You can then show that a rectangle having equal black and white areas (of overlapped checkerboard squares) is necessary and sufficient for determining that it has an integral side. Each rectangle with integral sides then has equal black and white squares, which combine to show that the large rectangle has the same property and thus an integral side itself.

Answer (score 5):

Among the fairly recent results, I like the proof of the joints conjecture (the final clean version that can be explained in a few sentences to anyone familiar with polynomials, derivatives, and elementary linear algebra). This may be a bit hard to the general audience though. Among all combinatorial geometry theorems, Bang's solution of Tarski's plank problem is unbeatable in my humble opinion. When presenting it, just do it for the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ assuming that all strips pass through the origin. It is then a one-liner (If the strips are $S_j=\{x:|(x,v_j)|\le |v_j|^2\}$ and $\sum_j |v_j|<1$, the point $y=\sum_j \pm v_j$ with the largest possible norm lies in the ball but in none of the strips). Once you have this idea in its pure form, the rest can be figured out in finite time. But how does one come up with ideas like that? (this is *not* a rhetoric question, by the way).

Answer (score 3):

Let me mention that the question is closely related to a more recent one [Proofs that require fundamentally new ways of thinking](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48771/proofs-that-require-fundamentally-new-ways-of-thinking) which I think also is about ingenuity in a sense. So indeed I was not sure where this answer better fits but I think the proof I would like to mention belongs here more.

This is Galvin's proof of the [Dinitz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitz_conjecture): The Dinitz conjecture asserted that if you give me an n by n array and in each square you put a set of size n then you can chose one element from each set so that all the chosen elements in a row or in a column are distinct.

If all the sets are the same (say 1,2,...,n) then you just want a Latin square. You can simply chose at position (i,j) i+j modulo n,

Galvin's proof derive Dinitz conjecture from the Gale-Shapley marriage theorem (Actually he used a theorem of Maffray, related to the stable marriage theorem.). It is short, elementary and extremely surprising. ( I will try to find a link.)

Answer (score 2):

Christian Blatter gave a wonderful proof of Pick's Theorem using thermodynamics (okay, it's really not that fancy, but it involves a thought experiment about heat distribution).  It originally appeared in Math. Mag.  Here is a free link: http://www.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Pick.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I like very much the proof of fundamental theorem of algebra (using the winding number around the origin), but it will  probably take too long to explain...

Answer (score 1):

A recent reference is "Street fighting mathematics" by Sanjoy Mahajan.

AT [http://www.amazon.com/Street-Fighting-Mathematics-Educated-Guessing-Opportunistic/dp/026251429X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/026251429X)

I have browse and read some part. It look as if it almost manages to render NavierStokes equation edible for an hard die finitist. It uses mainly dimensionality but is full of ingenuity.

Answer (score 1):

a.  Euler's computation of Zeta(2), (at first with only very weak, handwaving, or no convergence arguments), as redacted in Polya or [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeta2.html).   Obviously amazingly ingenious, and interesting for artists, connecting numbers and circles.   Requires unerstanding that a polynomial is equal to the product of its first degree factors, possibly it is too well known, however.    It also allows one to then revisit the convergence argument and show what mathematicians actually worry about, after the "flash of ingenuity"

b.   A lovely agument I heard a long time ago on sci.math relating to Sagan's book "Contact" in which a message is encoded in the bits of Pi.    Someone asked whether a deity could arrange for Pi to be a different real number.    Opinions went back and forth relating to spacetime, etc.  Then someone asked, in light of any of the familiar series expansions, "If Pi were different, which natural number would be missing or duplicated, and how might that be?"   Leads to a discussion of the Peano axioms.   Everyone goes home wondering.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alon Amit's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40337/ingenuity-in-mathematics?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment115632_40362) to [Kevin Buzzard's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/40362/112504) (on the equivalence between the "upon STOP flip over the top card" game vs. the "upon STOP flip over the last card") reminded me of the [Ants on a Meter Stick](https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ants-on-a-stick/) problem (which has been a favorite of mine since I first read it in the Harvey Mudd Fun Facts site):

> One hundred ants are dropped on a meter stick. Each ant is traveling either to the left or the right with constant speed 1 meter per minute. When two ants meet, they bounce off each other and reverse direction. When an ant reaches an end of the stick, it falls off.
>
> At some point all the ants will have fallen off. The time at which
> this happens will depend on the initial configuration of the ants.
>
> Question: over ALL possible initial configurations, what is the longest amount of time that you would need to wait to guarantee that the stick has no more ants?

The insight lies in the fact that this is equivalent to the "Ghost Ants on a Meter Stick" problem, where the ants pass right through each other instead of bouncing off each other.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this meets your requirement for being elementary, but the [Eilenberg Swindle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg_swindle) is very easy, very clever, and widely applicable.

Comment: This obviously doesn't meet the requirement for being elementary.  And widely applicable?  Only if you are a mathematician; this talk is for artists!!!

Comment: @Sheikraisinrollbank: The general scheme of the swindle could surely be adapted to a simpler problem, no?