# Dao's theorem on six circumcenters associated with a cyclic hexagon

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

This questions from [Ngo Quang Duong's paper](http://www.journal-1.eu/2016-2/Ngo-Quang-Duong-Dao-theorem-pp.40-47.pdf)

In 2013, O. T. Dao published without proof a theorem with title [Another seven circles theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/AnotherSevenCircles.shtml) in [Cut the Knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-the-Knot), a free site for popular expositionsof many topics in mathematics.

The calculation of barycentric coordinate for concurrence given by N. Dergiades takes [more than 72 pages A4](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/AdvancedPlaneGeometry/conversations/messages/1539). In 09-2014, N. Dergiades gave an elegant proof of this theorem and renamed this theorem: [Dao’s theorem on six circumcenters associated with a cyclic hexagon](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2014volume14/FG201424index.html). In 10-2014, T. Cohl, a Taiwan student, gave a synthetic proof for this theorem. Two proofs were published in the [Forum Geometricorum journal](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/).

> We consider the following configuration: Let $L_1, L_2, L_3, L_4, L_5, L_6$ be six lines and let $P_{ij}= L_i \cap L_j$, such that $P_{12},P_{23}, P_{34}, P_{45}, P_{56}, P_{61}$ lie on a circle. Let
> $(O_{ijk})$ is circle $(P_{ij}, P_{jk}, P_{ik})$ with center
> $O_{ijk}$. Let $(O_{ijk})$ meets $(O_{jkh})$ again at $P'_{jk}$. (We
> taking subscripts modulo 6.)

I am looking a solution for the problem as follows:

> **Problem 1 [Ngo Quang Duong](http://www.journal-1.eu/2016-2/Ngo-Quang-Duong-Dao-theorem-pp.40-47.pdf):** Let $P_{12}P_{45}, P_{34}P_{61}, P_{56}P_{23}$ are concurrent at $P$. Then six points $P'_{12}$, $P'_{23}$, $P'_{34}$, $P'_{45}$, $P'_{56}$, $P'_{61}$ lie on a circle.

[image]

PS: I posted this topic because the **problem 1** look like [Miquel's Pentagram Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MiquelsPentagramTheorem.html)

Comment: Would O.T. Dao be the OP? If so, from one mathematician to another: Don't refer to your own theorems as `remarkable', even if they are!

Comment: @Jon, cut her some slack. Most foreign speakers aren't familiar with linguistic etiquette in English--how to assume the proper tone. "I published a theorem illustrating the remarkable / beautiful connections between ..."  would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Tom: You are right! The wording you suggest is just fine. Thanks for providing a positive suggestion!

Comment: @Jon, I'm sure that's exactly the sentiment the OP intended to convey.

Comment: Dear @TomCopeland OP mean?

Comment: @Oai, OP = original poster = the original author of the question = you

Comment: Yes, I have one question-the problem 1, Ngo Quang Dương have one-the problem 2. Did you mean I souldn't posted my original question? @TomCopeland

Comment: @TomCopeland, I removed word "remarkable" ; because I understand remarkable mean: to deverse note.

Comment: @ Oai Thanh Dao: Yes you should have posted the question. Both Tom and I are trying to help you with a tricky part of English for mathematicians. Please see Tom's suggestion for language: "I published a theorem illustrating the remarkable / beautiful connections between ..."

Comment: Oai, it's just a matter of translation. Most Americans don't understand how difficult it can be for non-native English speakers to express their sentiments in English and often jump to the wrong conclusion. Hard to explain. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I thank to You dear Mister @TomCopeland

Comment: I thank to You dear Mister @JonBannon

Comment: Sorry, even my last comment is full of idioms difficult for most Asians to understand.

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào : one never says "I thank to you..."; it's just "Thank you...".

Comment: You should make clearer that the text is copied and pasted from the first quoted article (e.g. use > or " " to mark quotation). In fact, it would be better and clearer to restate the question in your own words.

Comment: I thank to You, How I can do it? @BenoîtKloeckner

Comment: Use "edit" below your post. You should probably concentrate on the core problem and notation, and keep the mention of Duong's paper for more context.

Answer (score 2):

- The solution of problem in our paper [On an Extension of Miquel's Theorem to a Cyclic Hexagon](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342144858_On_an_Extension_of_Miquel%27s_Theorem_to_a_Cyclic_Hexagon);
- Relative configuration in here [On the eight circles theorem and its dual](https://ijgeometry.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/49-53.pdf)