# Three homothetic centers are collinear

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

I am looking a proof for the problem as follows:

> Let a convex hexagon, such that its principal diagonals are concurrent. For each side of the hexagon, extend the adjacent sides to their intersection, forming a triangle exterior to the given side. Then show that:  Three external (or internal) [homothetic centers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotheticCenter.html) of three pair circumcircle of opposite triangles are collinear.

[Please see the applet in Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/jrJZHnAX)

[image]

PS: The line through the three external homothetic centers are perpendicular to the line through three internal homothetic centers.

[Another applet: Three homothetic centers are collinear associated  a  circumscribed conic hexagon](https://www.geogebra.org/m/yUvUAnBg)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you coming up with all these facts? Are you just playing around with GeoGebra (or a similar tool) and noticing that such-and-such relation always holds?

Comment: @Wojowu When I construct [Dao's theorem on six circumcenters](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234053/daos-theorem-on-six-circumcenters-associated-with-a-cyclic-hexagon), I found this property true with a cyclic hexagon with principal diagonals are concurrent . Later I generalization for arbitrary hexagon with principal diagonals are concurrent.

[See Geogebra:](https://www.geogebra.org/m/jrJZHnAX)

Comment: While you do specify it ... are you sure this property is solely for a _convex_ hexagon ? and not valid for a general case.

Comment: General case: Alway have three homothetic centers are collinear, and three other homothetic centers are collinear. But exactly three external homothetic center are collinear and three internal homothetic center are collinear we need convex hexagon

Comment: @ARi maybe the result true for generalization case

Comment: If you can formulate a statement for the general case - it may probably be more straightforward

Comment: I think I don't need, because Monge's theorem states: [Let there be three circles of different radii lying completely outside each other](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/threecircles.shtml), but I think the Monge theorem maybe true in general case.

Answer (score 2):

At least for the external homothetic centers, this follows from [Monge's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge's_theorem), which actually tells you that "for any three circles in a plane, none of which is completely inside one of the others, the intersection points of each of the three pairs of external tangent lines are collinear".

Comment: Which 3 circles do you apply that to?  The three points in the question are shown as arising from 6 circles instead.

Comment: Yes, I think the proof of @ihm is mistake. Monge's theorem apply with three circles. But here is six circles

Comment: The false proof